# Update / download the actual file from the SVN

Tags: linux, svn

I had an emergency change something in the file without going through committing to SVN. That is, instead of to the local computer to make changes and commit the this, I immediately changed the file on the server (for that was the reason).

Tell me, how can I download a file from a server on a computer?

Comment: To that you provide the wrong kind of context. The important context is how did you get the file to the server in the first place (and the answer is, well, you get it back the same way).

Comment: I'm not sure how you did that (unless you changed the SVN properties of the file, which you can do on the server). In any case, if you want to get this changed file, why not simply do a checkout of it?

Answer (score 1):

**If** *your server's space is Working Copy* **and** your *local workplace is Working Copy* (and both WCs are binded to the same Repo-URL) you can commit from server & update from local

If your server isn't WC, you have more headache around syncing diverged changes